# How to test a method that receives 2 lists as parameters and a Properties to generate a json

Tags: java, junit4, powermock

I need to test a method that basically contains the generation of a json with different data, the method receives 2 lists and a Properties as parameters.

I put code of the method to test:

```
public boolean getServiceLynxs(List<DataGenerateFiles> dataGenerateFilesList, List<String> 
    notSendLynxs, Properties params) throws IOException {
    boolean result = false;
    
    try {
        logger.info("Llamando REST_LYNXS");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfNM1720 = new SimpleDateFormat((String) params.get("SDF_NM17_20"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdfNM29 = new SimpleDateFormat((String) params.get("SDF_NM29"));
        Date dateFecha = new Date();
        String thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

        if (dataGenerateFilesList != null) {
            for (DataGenerateFiles dataGenerateFiles : dataGenerateFilesList) {
                
                if(!notSendLynxs.contains(dataGenerateFiles.getCdUsuario())) {
                    
                    Map<String, String> jsonObject = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                    jsonObject.put("NM01", "NM");                                            jsonObject.put("NM02", "MX");
                    jsonObject.put("NM03", "21");                                            jsonObject.put("NM04", dataGenerateFiles.getCdTipoBiometrico());
                    jsonObject.put("NM05", "LBMR");                                          jsonObject.put("NM06", dataGenerateFiles.getCdUsuario());
                    jsonObject.put("NM07", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM08", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM09", "3");                                             jsonObject.put("NM10", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM11", "LBMR");                                          jsonObject.put("NM12", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM13", dataGenerateFiles.getCdTelefonoEnrolamiento());   jsonObject.put("NM14", thisIp);
                    jsonObject.put("NM15", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM16", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM17", sdfNM1720.format(dateFecha));                    jsonObject.put("NM18", "HV");
                    jsonObject.put("NM19", "WYDH");                                          jsonObject.put("NM20", sdfNM1720.format(dateFecha));
                    jsonObject.put("NM21", dataGenerateFiles.getStEstatusBiometrico());      jsonObject.put("NM22", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM23", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM24", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM25", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM26", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM27", dataGenerateFiles.getCdTelefonoEnrolamiento());   jsonObject.put("NM28", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM29", sdfNM29.format(dateFecha));                       jsonObject.put("NM30", "IVR1");
                    jsonObject.put("NM31", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM32", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM33", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM34", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM35", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM36", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM37", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM38", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM39", "");                                              jsonObject.put("NM40", "");
                    jsonObject.put("NM41", "");
                    
                    String json = jsonObject.entrySet().stream()
                            .map(x -> "\"" + x.getKey() + "\":\"" + x.getValue() + "\"")
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));

                    connectRestLynxs(params);
                    
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();                
                    outputStream.write(json.getBytes());
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();

                    logger.info("Respuesta LYNXS {}: " + httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    logger.info("JSON_REST_LYNXS {}:" + jsonObject);
                    
                    leerDatosJson();
                }

            }
              result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error Exception getServiceLynxs {}" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am attaching a test method that I have at the moment, I have been trying to test the method, but I have not succeeded

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ RestLynxs.class, PropertiesCache.class })
public class RestLynxsTest {

@InjectMocks
RestLynxs restLynxsMock;

Properties configProp = new Properties();

DataGenerateFiles dataGenerateFiles;
List<DataGenerateFiles> dataGenerateFilesList;
List<String> notSendLynxs;
String paramDateFormatNM1720 = "20230425130930";
String paramDateFormatNM29 = "20230425171231000275";

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertiesCache.class);
    dataGenerateFiles = new DataGenerateFiles();
    dataGenerateFiles.setCdTipoBiometrico("HV");
    dataGenerateFiles.setCdUsuario("D0000000");
    dataGenerateFiles.setCdTelefonoEnrolamiento("1234567890");
    dataGenerateFiles.setStEstatusBiometrico("000");
}

/**
 * Test method for
 * {@link com.bbva.bo.RestLynxs#getServiceLynxs(java.util.List, java.util.List)}.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Test
public void testGetServiceLynxs() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./FileTest/configHV_PU.properties");
    configProp.load(inputStream);
    dataGenerateFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataGenerateFilesList.add(dataGenerateFiles);
    notSendLynxs = new ArrayList<>();
    notSendLynxs.add("D0000000");

    Map<String, String> dataJsonList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    dataJsonList.put("NM04", dataGenerateFiles.getCdTipoBiometrico());

    List<String> listado = dataJsonList.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

    boolean valueReceived = restLynxsMock.getServiceLynxs(dataGenerateFilesList, notSendLynxs, configProp);
    assertTrue(valueReceived);
}
```

}

Comment: "I have not succeeded": what *specifically* does that mean?

Comment: You haven't told us what actual problem you've hit - please do so. Whatever the case, refactor your monolithic method by composing it of smaller, easily-testable methods.

Comment: Bohemian The problem is that I can't manage to test what I have inside the map